# Deactivate feature using cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I want to **exclude one, already written feature** when running all my cucumber features.

*Why?*
Because the feature is already implemented (bdd) but I don't have time to implement it now, but I don't wanna loose it.

Any help is very appreciated.

Code sample:

```
@shallbeexcluded
Feature: Exclude me
  In order to learn more
  As an stack overflow user
  I want to find more information

  Scenario: Find what I'm looking for
    Given I open the Google search page in my browser
    When I search for "rspec"
    Then I should see a link to http://rspec.info/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a built in tag in cucumber: `@wip` (for Work In Progress, inspired by Kanban principles)

To run work in progress features (tagged @wip):

```
rake cucumber:wip
```

To run other features (not tagged @wip):

```
rake cucumber:ok
```

This is briefly discussed on http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/cucumber-backgrounder

Comment: Works fine for me. 
Thank you for the solution and the link to additional documentation!